# Regex match adjacent digits after second occurrence of character

Tags: python, regex

Stuck with the following issue:

I have a string 'ABC.123.456XX' and I want to use regex to extract the 3 numeric characters that come after the second period. Really struggling with this and would appreciate any new insights, this is the closest I got but its not really close to what I want:

```
'.*\.(.*?\.\d{3})'
```

I appreciate any help in advance - thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expression might also work just OK:

```
[^\r\n.]+\.[^\r\n.]+\.([0-9]{3})
```

#### Test

```
import re

regex = r'[^\r\n.]+\.[^\r\n.]+\.([0-9]{3})'
string = '''
ABC.123.456XX
ABCOUOU.123123123.000871XX
ABCanything_else.123123123.111871XX
'''

print(re.findall(regex, string))
```

#### Output

```
['456', '000', '111']
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/37uBqa/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/37uBqa/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

Answer (score 2):

If your input will always be in a similar format, like `xxx.xxx.xxxxx`, then one solution is string manipulation:

```
>>> s = 'ABC.123.456XX'
>>> '.'.join(s.split('.')[2:])[0:3]
```

**Explanation**

In the line `'.'.join(s.split('.')[2:])[0:3]`:

- `s.split('.')` splits the string into the list `['ABC', '123', '456XX']`
- `'.'.join(s.split('.')[2:])` joins the remainder of the list after the second element, so `'456XX'`
- `[0:3]` selects the substring from index 0 to index 2 (inclusive), so the result is `456`

Comment: Hey - forgot to add there may be more decimals after that I may want to include so I can't really use split. Also, I am trying to learn Regex so I am hoping to find a solution using that. Thank you though.

Comment: @sgeorgec No worries! Props for learning regex, but that doesn't necessarily mean you can't use `split()`. Updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

Dot, not-Dot twice then the 3 digits follow in capture group 1

`[^.]*(?:\.[^.]*){2}(\d{3})`

https://regex101.com/r/qWpfHx/1

Expanded

```
 [^.]* 
 (?: \. [^.]* ){2}
 ( \d{3} )                     # (1)
```