# list comprehension with Regex to match whole item if it has matching number between two specific characters

Tags: python, regex, list

This question is the continuation [of this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74744103/regex-python-find-match-items-on-list-that-have-the-same-digit-between-the-sec/74744288?noredirect=1#comment131931854_74744288)
I have the following list :

```
list_paths=[imgs/foldeer/img_ABC_21389_1.tif.tif,
imgs/foldeer/img_ABC_15431_10.tif.tif,
imgs/foldeer/img_GHC_561321_2.tif.tif,
imgs_foldeer/img_BCL_871125_21.tif.tif,
...]
```

I want to be able to run a for loop to match string with specific number,which is **the number between the third occurrence of "_" to the ".tif.tif"**,
for example, when number is 1, the string to be matched is "imgs/foldeer/img_ABC_21389_1.tif.tif"   ,

for number 2, the match string will be "imgs/foldeer/img_GHC_561321_2.tif.tif".

For that, I wanted to use regex expression using list comprehension. [Based on this answer,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58294532/regex-match-adjacent-digits-after-second-occurrence-of-character) I have tested this regex expression on Regex101:

```
number = 10
pattern = rf"^\S*?/(?:[^\s_/]+_){{3}}{number}\.tif\b[^\s/]*$"

indices = [for x in data if re.search(pattern, x)]
```

But this doesn't match anything, and also doesn't make sure that it will take the exact number, so if number is 1, it might also select items with number 10 .

**My end goal is to be able to match items in the list that have the request number between the 2nd occurrence of "_" to the first occirance of ".tif" , using regex expression, looking for help with the regex expression.**

The output should be the whole path  and not only the number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your existing regex pattern a bit to use the exact matching for the ending `.tif.tif`

```
import re
data=['imgs/foldeer/img_ABC_21389_1.tif.tif',
'imgs/foldeer/img_ABC_15431_10.tif.tif',
'imgs/foldeer/img_GHC_561321_2.tif.tif',
'imgs_foldeer/img_BCL_871125_21.tif.tif']

number = 2
pattern = rf"^\S*?/(?:[^\s_/]+_){{3}}{number}\.tif\.tif$"
print([x for x in data if re.search(pattern, x)])
```

**Output:**

```
['imgs/foldeer/img_ABC_15431_2.tif.tif']
```

---

*My end goal is to be able to match items in the list that have the request number between the 2nd occurrence of "_" to the first occirance of ".tif" , using regex expression, looking for help with the regex expression.*

```
number = 1
pattern = rf"^\S*?/(?:[^\s_/]+_){{3}}{number}\.tif\.tif$"
print([x for x in data if re.search(pattern, x)])
```

**Output:**

```
['imgs/foldeer/img_ABC_21389_1.tif.tif']
```

As you can see, when number is 1, only the pattern with 1 is matched(even though we have a pattern having 10 in the data) with output being - `['imgs/foldeer/img_ABC_21389_1.tif.tif']`